# Coldfusion string replace with ReReplace

Tags: regex, string, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to replace spaces in a string with underscore for slug creation using RegEx. Its works fine when there is one space. But when there is two consecutive spaces or a space followed by an underscore and vice versa(`' _' OR '_ '`) its replaced as `__`. How can i overcome this? that is **I want a single underscore instead of double or triple**. Any help would be appreciated.

My code for replacing is similar to this.

```
rereplace(lCase('this is a sample _string'),'[ ]','_','all')
```

Comment: You don't tell us what you want to have happen *instead*?

Comment: Oh. I want a single underscore instead of double or triple.

Comment: Cheers. Best to update the question, not simple add a comment though (for future reference). Answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, based on your revised requirement:

```
original = "string with_mix _ of  spaces__and_ _underscores__  __to_ _test  with";
updated = reReplace(original, "[ _]+", "_", "all");
writeOutput(updated);
```

Results in:

```
string_with_mix_of_spaces_and_underscores_to_test_with
```

Is that to spec?

Comment: +1 Works perfect. Could you please update the answer to remove the remove space and Underscore at End of the string?